# What does it mean when you set an array[index] equal to quotation marks?

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, hash, pattern-matching

I've been working on a problem where the goal is to take a string and return the longest repeated pattern if a pattern is present. For example, if the string is "aabbbaa", "yes aa" would be returned. If the string is "aavbbbvaabbb", "yes bbb" would be returned. I took a look at someone else's solution and believe to understand each piece of code aside from this one line which seems to be key: `copy[idx..idx2]=""`

Here's the whole solution:

```
def PatternChaser(str)
  patterns = {}

  (0..str.length-1).each do |idx| 
    (idx + 1..str.length - 1).each do |idx2| 
        copy = str.dup
        chunk = str[idx..idx2]
        len = chunk.length
        copy[idx..idx2] = ""
        patterns[chunk] = len if copy.include?(chunk) && !patterns.include?(chunk)
     end
  end
  return "no null" if patterns.empty?
  patterns.each { |k,v| return "yes" + " " + k if v == patterns.values.max }
end

puts PatternChaser(STDIN.gets)
```

Forgive me if this is fairly common syntax. I've been coding for less than a year thus far and haven't been able to find an answer so far on StackOverflow. Help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: You remove the content of the string between `idx` and `idx2`, hence you are deleting characters.

Comment: In the first example, is "bb" repeated too, as in *may repetitions overlap*?

Comment: The answer is given in the doc for the instance method [String#\[\]=](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D).

Comment: "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)" would be good reading for you.

Comment: That `array[index]` in your question's title seems a bit misleading given that `copy` is a string and `idx..idx` is a range.

Comment: @Stefan A string is technically considered an array, but you're right that the "index" could have been written instead as "idx..idx". However, the main point of the question was to figure out what happens when you set that to "", which my question successfully got the answer to in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks bud! I gave it a read and it seems I followed the outlined principles quite well without having read them before. The question was very explicitly clear, posted in the appropriate environment after independent research was done, and no one seemed to have a problem interpreting the question considering it was answered swiftly in a way that bridged my gap of knowledge. I do appreciate the resource you shared though as I'm new to the platform and it didn't hurt to read!

Comment: @greybeard Very astute! I wouldn't have even thought of that. Apparently overlapping patterns are not considered to be "repeated" in this instance, which can be seen from the solution I posted. That possibility must not have even been considered by the makers of the problem though, considering that they didn't address it!

Comment: @savethemichaels _"A string is technically considered an array"_ – on an abstract level maybe, if you see a string as an sequence of characters. But Ruby's `String` class is not build upon the `Array` class. And although [`Array#[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) and [`String#[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) have a lot in common, they are entirely different methods. To understand what `copy[...] = ...` does, you have to know what kind of object `copy` is and where its `[]=` method comes from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A string can be seen as a sequence of charaters. By writing:

```
copy[idx..idx2]=""
```

You are setting the characters between `idx` and `idx2` to the empty string, so that means that you are removing the characters from `idx` (inclusive) and `idx2` (inclusive) from the `copy` string.

For example:

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "foobar"
=> "foobar"
irb(main):002:0> s[1..3] = ""
=> ""
irb(main):003:0> s
=> "far"
```

We can also insert another string that contains less, an equal amount or more characters than the sequence. For example:

```
irb(main):007:0> s = "foobar"
=> "foobar"
irb(main):008:0> s[1..3] = "oofoob"
=> "oofoob"
irb(main):009:0> s
=> "foofoobar"
```

Comment: Ahh, that definitely explains it. I understand now. Thanks for the instantaneous response!!